# Query that returns a single column containing data from multiple columns (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write an oracle SQL query that returns a single column containing values from multiple columns.

I have a table named CLIENT

```
clientid firstname Lastname
1        Steve     Smith
2        James     Hill
```

I want to return a single column "ALL" like so:

```
ALL
1
2
Steve
James
Smith
Hill
```

Is there a simple way to write this query?

Comment: Have you looked into `UNION` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This involves `UNION`

```
SELECT ClientID AS [All]
   FROM Client
  UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName
   FROM Client
  UNION ALL
SELECT LastName
   FROM Client
```

Comment: @Steve glad to help. Feel free to mark it as the answer.